# Funny graph of $x!$ by a graphing program

Tags: factorial

I obtained [a bizarre graph of $x!$](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/hzq99lkn4h), a function which I believe is only defined at positive integer domain.

What causes such an error?. It would be interesting if someone can explain the method such a graphing software uses to compute $x!$

I have attached the image of the graph below.

[image: [a bizarre graph of $x!$](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/hzq99lkn4h)]

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function

Comment: "is only defined at positive integer domain." - as @Henry indicates, it is possible to extend the definition of the factorial so that it is sensible for arbitrary complex arguments, except possibly at the nonpositive integers.

Comment: I suppose a [plot of the factorial for *complex* arguments](http://i.stack.imgur.com/YfThN.png) would be even more shocking for you...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right that, by the traditional definition of $x!$, it is only defined at the integers. However, we can analytically continue the factorial function to all real numbers (except, as Peter notes in the comments, for all negative integers and $0$). [This continuation (along with a shift) is known as the Gamma Function.](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GammaFunction.html)

However, note that there are other continuations of the factorial function. The one pictured here is the Gamma Function. [Here are some other continuations](http://www.luschny.de/math/factorial/hadamard/HadamardsGammaFunction.html) which interlope $x!$.

Comment: "...to all real numbers" save negative integers, yes? (At least  for $\Gamma$. Other continuations don't have this issue)

Comment: @Peter, *nonpositive* integers. In fact, $\Gamma$ can be extended to the complex plane, not just the real line.

Comment: @J.M. *sigh* =) $0$ is zero. Not positive, nor negative. For me, at least.

Comment: "other continuations" - see e.g. [this](http://www.luschny.de/math/factorial/hadamard/HadamardsGammaFunctionMJ.html).

Comment: -1 such a poor explanation, doesn't really say anything

Comment: @Celeritas sorry you feel that way. I do believe that my answer is comprehensive. The original question asks "Why is $n!$ graphed at places other than its domain?" and the answer is "Because that's not the domain of their factorial function." There's no intrinsic mathematical explanation of why this function was the one we chose, maybe if history was different we'd have a different Gamma function. There are chapters of books on the Gamma function and its behavior, and I won't attempt to reproduce it here to please you.

Comment: @GeorgeV.Williams if you'd like to improve your answer you could explain why it makes sense to interpolate n! with another function.

Comment: @Celeritas, no thanks.

Comment: I believe we've chosen the function we did due to its property $x\Gamma(x)=\Gamma(x+1)$, which is analogous to $(n+1)n!=(n+1)!$, but works for all $x$, not only integers. This is the property which leads to $\Gamma(0)=\Gamma(1)/0$ and similar for all other nonpositive integers.

Comment: @Rusian, in the second link above there are some other functions which satisfy that property. If you also stipulate that $\Gamma(1) = 1$ and $\Gamma$ log-convex as well then that does uniquely define the Gamma function (Bohr–Mollerup theorem).

Answer (score 1):

I guess that program is *Desmos*.

The graph is alright.
It's because of the interesting relation between Gamma function and the factorial function.
Gamma of x is denoted by $\Gamma{(x)}$
The relation is $\Gamma{(x+1)}=x!$.
This is often used to extend the domain of the factorial function. Using this we can prove that $(\frac{1}{2})!=\frac{\sqrt{π}}{2}$

Comment: You don't have to guess, the link in the OP already leads to desmos.com.