# Derivative of the function $(x)!$.

Tags: calculus, derivatives, factorial

I had been learning calculus. So what I was thinking about is what us differentiation if $(x)!$. I know. 'n 'th derivative of $x^n$ is $x!$ but it isn''t helping me to solve this problem.

Comment: the $n^{\rm{th}}$ derivative of $x^n$ is $n!$, which is a natural number, it's not a function in $x$

Comment: Some related posts:[The derivative of $x!$ and its continuity](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1304886/the-derivative-of-x-and-its-continuity) and [Finding $\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx} x!$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/911957/finding-frac-mathrm-d-mathrm-dx-x). (Maybe there are other similar posts on this site.)

Answer (score 4):

Derivating $x!$ makes no sense since it is defined only for natural numbers, and therefore, it is not a continuous function, necessary condition to the existence of the derivative.